# Why was my comment removed?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-comments

I posted a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696564/how-to-loop-through-a-firebase-datasnapshot-sub-childrens-flutter), that said:

> for anyone checking this question, you can also check my answer here that is explained in details [Flutter: The method forEach isn't defined for the class DataSnapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51759155/flutter-the-method-foreach-isnt-defined-for-the-class-datasnapshot)

Then I saw that OP ([of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696564/how-to-loop-through-a-firebase-datasnapshot-sub-childrens-flutter)) felt entitled, and marked the other question as a duplicate, even though it is not a duplicate(the question is a completely different case).

So, I flagged the comment as no longer needed, which was declined by a moderator. 
But why was my comment deleted from that question? All what I was doing is trying to help any person checking it to understand how to use both of these frameworks.

Comment: Did the moderator not give a reason?

Comment: The comment that says "possible duplicate of..." is the one that I flagged, and no they just said "declined". It's fine that they declined (dont know why..) but just wondering why my comment was deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense flagging auto-generated comments like the _"possible duplicate"_ ones. That would be akin to flagging flags/votes, which we do not do.

Comment: okay, that is not a problem at all, the problem is why my comment got deleted?

Comment: So comments like this get deleted? Lol, I also link to other answers sometimes if they are related, because `Related` section is usually useless in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TLDR: Your comment wasn't needed to improve or clarify the post it was written under, so a mod responding to a *no longer needed* flag would have reason to honor the flag and delete the comment.

---

I'm not familiar with the technologies involved in the questions... but if the question is not a duplicate (answer to *B* does not apply to *A*), and someone flagged that comment as "no longer needed", they wouldn't be *wrong*.

That comment didn't bring anything needed for question *A*: **it didn't ask for more information or suggested improvements to the question.**

The comment didn't even address the question asker, but **future readers**, and didn't actually refer to the specific post it was written under, but to the subject in general. Information for future readers should be incorporated into the actual posts (either a question or an answer).

It's not a *rude* comment, it is not an *abusive* comment, it is not *unfriendly or unkind* but it doesn't serve any additional purpose for that question. The main purpose of comments is **to help improve or clarify a post**.

Your answer in the other question might be tangentially relevant (I'm taking your word for it being relevant and not a dupe), but so would be answers to possibly dozens of other questions. We do not need comments advertising their existance for each of those.

In that sense, a *no longer needed* flag could have easily had been acted upon by a moderator.

Comment: Well that's a non-sense. We should allow linking to related questions because afaics `Related` section is useless. It's not like it's clogging anything... Does it?

Comment: @yivi The thing is the mod that removed this comment did not even read it, because if he did, then he probably would not have removed it. I can give you many examples where people post their answers on other questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-to-remove-local-untracked-files-from-the-current-git-working-tree?rq=1#comment25973822_61212 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673407/how-do-i-clear-my-local-working-directory-in-git?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment85638172_673407

Comment: @yivi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit?rq=1#comment36675816_4114095 those are a small sample of examples. It has always been the case where users post there answers on other questions, I can tag many users who I seen do that alot. I marked this answer as correct even though I dont agree, because honestly there is no point in this discussion if the mod who did this is not gonna reply here. All the answers are gonna be opinion based.

Comment: Flutter is still new and me posting my answer in the comment was just a way to help new people trying flutter out. So, they understand how to retrieve data and stuff like that(since it is not documented in a good way)

Answer (score 1):

Your comment shouldn't be deleted because AFAIU you linked to a related question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

> **You should submit a comment if you want to**:
>
> Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a **link to a related question**, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).`

I argue that these types of comments should stay because they bring value (related question) for the future readers. If they are deleted prior to question/answer being modified with the relevant link, then that *value is lost*.
And if that link can be *justifiably* deleted at any time (meaning as soon as the comment is posted without post being modified with the link), then it was not allowed to be posted in the first place, thus there is a conflict with the quote above.

So with that in mind, it seems to me that your comment was vandalized because it wasn't edited in the question or the answer.

Comment: You are emphasizing _"link to related question"_, when I think the part to emphasize is "_transient information_".

Comment: @yivi You might be correct, and still he's allowed to post it AFAIU.

Comment: Nobody said "they are not allowed to post it". They are allowed to post it. But it can be deleted afterwards. It's transient information anyway.

Comment: @yivi  I argue here that the value of the comment is lost for the future readers if it gets deleted. And what's the time frame then when it's outdated then? When some answer is marked as accepted? If it is justifiably deleted, then it implies that it was _not allowed_ in the first place.

Comment: No, it doesn't imply that at all. Someone flagging _"no longer needed"_ is not saying _"this shouldn't have been posted at all"_. It's simply saying _"this is no longer needed to improve this post"_.

Comment: @Traxo: Information for future readers shouldn't be in comments. It should be in the answer/question. A comment is, by definition, transient and can be removed at any time.

Comment: @yivi wrote `Someone flagging "no longer needed" is not saying "this shouldn't have been posted at all". It's simply saying "this is no longer needed to improve this post".` Ok _sorta_ good point... That's why I asked for time frame. So if the question/answer is edited with relevant link then the comment might get deleted (thus no longer needed and I might agree with that). However, if none was edited with the link from a comment, and comment gets deleted, then it was apparently not allowed. The value which is then lost is the related question.

Comment: There is no "time frame". As soon as someone flags a comment, it can be deleted. It can even be deleted before that, if a mod happens to see a the comment and judges it to be deletion worthy.

Comment: @yivi Sry, I meant when it _should_ be deleted because it's no longer needed. So to rephrase: After link in the comment is provided, _when_ is the comment considered as _no longer needed_? From what you guys are saying it seems to me that it's no longer needed when question/answer is edited with that very link.

Comment: @Traxo, The answer is "until someone feels the need to flag as _No longer needed_". You are asking a question which is subjective, it can't be quantified. If you feel strongly that your related post should be part of an answer, answer the question yourself and include a "Related: XYZ" with your link. I do this often.

Comment: Again, no time frame. As soon as it's flagged, it can be evaluated. In the case of the comment being discussed, it's a simple matter of reading the comment and seeing that it can't be used to improve the post, so it's no longer needed (if it ever was).